# Shader does not change color of surface

Tags: shaders, color

I don't know wether it is just me or that is a bug but still:
When I'm trying to change surface color through shader (Pricipled BDSF) surface color doesn't react at all. All other things do have an impacts, such as roughness or bump maps.
I am not quite sure under what surcumstances this odd thing happenes, but it does quite frequently. Hoever, some other objects inb the scene seem to be not affected by this problem.
Did enyone encounter such issue before or there is something I've missed in the settings, or is it just a stupid bug?

Best regards and thanks for unswers,
Erik 
[image: Example02]

[image: Example01]

Comment: Please provide a .blend of the scene with the minimum size showing the problem so I can have a look at it.

Comment: Agree, a .blend file would be great